# Erro depois de chamar o Evento

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

Depois de chamar o Evento de clique no botão, o cálculo aparece sem resultado e o HTML que inseri através do JS some da tela logo após a chamada. PS: Ignore o CSS em desenvolvimento!

```js
/*
    Forma de fazer números aleatórios em um intervalo;

    const num1 = 5
    const num2 = 10

    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (num2 - num1)) + num1)
*/

// Pegar os dois números e inserir no cálculo ---------------------------------

const number1 = document.querySelector("#sorteador1").value
const number2 = document.querySelector("#sorteador2").value
const resultHtml = document.querySelector("#result")
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
let calculo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number2 - number1)) + number1

//Evento de clique no Botão "Sortear" -----------------------------------------

function lucky() {
    return resultHtml.innerHTML = `<h3>O número sorteado foi: ${calculo}</h3>`
}

btn.addEventListener("click", lucky)
```

```css
:root {
    --color-header-bg: #f8dbc9;
    --color-font: #033d68;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffe7d9;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--color-header-bg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-font);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

img {
    transform: translateX(900px);
    border-radius: 30%;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 205px 500px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    border: 3px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
    background-color: var(--color-header-bg)
}

span {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 5px 3px 0px #F2D4C2;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

button {
    border: 3px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 80px;
    width: 790px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: 570px;
}

.sortear {
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #F2D4C2;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagem/SORTEADOR-FAVICON.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sorteador</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <nav>
                <img src="Imagem/SORTEADOR-header.png" alt="Logo Sorteador" srcset="" width="150px">
            </nav>
        </a>
    </header>

    <main>
        <form id="formulary">
            <span>Sortear de </span>
                <input type="number" id="sorteador1" name="num1" min="1" max="10000">
            <span> a </span>
                <input type="number" id="sorteador2" name="num1" min="1" max="10000">
        </form>

        <button form="formulary" id="btn">
            <span type="button" class="sortear">Sortear</spa>
        </button>

        <div id="result"></div>

        <script src="btn.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!

Bom, dois pontos principais:

Quanto a atualização da página, por padrão, o clique no botão criava um submit no seu formulário. Para impedir isso, no evento de clique do botão é necessário incluir um `preventDefault();`

Mais sobre o preventDefault(): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Com relação a execução do sorteio, o código que pegava os valores e fazia o cálculo estava sendo executado quando a página era carregada, antes de o usuário colocar os valores ou apertar o botão. Nesse caso como você precisa dele apenas depois do preenchimento e do clique, ele deve ser chamado com o evento do clique.

Nesse caso, coloquei ele dentro da sua função lucky para testar. Para organizar mais seu código, você pode separar ele dentro de outra função depois.

Segue o código modificado abaixo

```js
/*
    Forma de fazer números aleatórios em um intervalo;

    const num1 = 5
    const num2 = 10

    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * (num2 - num1)) + num1)
*/

//Evento de clique no Botão "Sortear" -----------------------------------------

function lucky(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    
    // Pegar os dois números e inserir no cálculo ---------------------------------
    const number1 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#sorteador1").value);
    const number2 = parseInt(document.querySelector("#sorteador2").value);
    const resultHtml = document.querySelector("#result");
    const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    let calculo = Math.floor(Math.random() * (number2 - number1)) + number1;

    return resultHtml.innerHTML = `<h3>O número sorteado foi: ${calculo}</h3>`
}

btn.addEventListener("click", lucky)
```

```css
:root {
    --color-header-bg: #f8dbc9;
    --color-font: #033d68;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffe7d9;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--color-header-bg);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--color-font);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

img {
    transform: translateX(900px);
    border-radius: 30%;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
}

form {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 205px 500px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    border: 3px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
    background-color: var(--color-header-bg)
}

span {
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 5px 3px 0px #F2D4C2;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

button {
    border: 3px solid var(--color-font);
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 80px;
    width: 790px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: 570px;
}

.sortear {
    font-size: 75px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: var(--color-font);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #F2D4C2;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 4px #F2D4C2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagem/SORTEADOR-FAVICON.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Sorteador</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <nav>
                <img src="Imagem/SORTEADOR-header.png" alt="Logo Sorteador" srcset="" width="150px">
            </nav>
        </a>
    </header>

    <main>
        <form id="formulary">
            <span>Sortear de </span>
                <input type="number" id="sorteador1" name="num1" min="1" max="10000">
            <span> a </span>
                <input type="number" id="sorteador2" name="num1" min="1" max="10000">
        </form>

        <button form="formulary" id="btn">
            <span type="button" class="sortear">Sortear</spa>
        </button>

        <div id="result"></div>

        <script src="btn.js"></script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Abraço!